# Single Sign on of Oracle forms to a webpage

Tags: authentication, oauth, oracleforms

I got a requirement to pass the login to an URL from an oracle form, so that the user does not need to login again.

Is it possible to use Oauth to do the single sign on from Oracle form to an URL???
Or there is other method to achieve that? THanks.!